# How to generate temporary public-key using html5

Tags: javascript, html, public-key-encryption, public-key, temporary

How to generate a public/private key pair in the user's browser,

This key must be:

- temporary (not saved for ever, valid only for the current session).
- generated in a cross browser/system manner without prompting the user for any input.
- allow access to the public key's hash for validation purposes.

I tried using `<keygen>` but it requires using forms and user intervention.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [WebCrypto](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/)

Specifically, [`crypto.subtle.generateKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) will do the key generation.

- The key can be temporary as long as you discard it securely and/or invalidate it after its desired validity period has expired.  Depending on how your system works, you may want to validate the expiry/validity of a given key by rolling it into the hash.
- Here is a [tutorial](http://qnimate.com/asymmetric-encryption-using-web-cryptography-api/) which offers a cross-browser solution.
- Hashing the key (and/or other data) can be done using other parts of the WebCrypto API (see [`crypto.subtle.digest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest))

Comment: thanks for your valuable information, i'll give it a look, and get back with the results

Comment: `crypto.subtle.generateKey` is supported only by Firefox 34, Chrome 37, and Edge.